# create SAS dataset with variable number of attributes

Tags: sas

I need to create a dataset in SAS, with a variable no of attribute names.
Im not so proficient in SAS, so writing the logic in normal lang

```
for(i=1 to 10)
{
   for (j=1 to n)
   {
      Combinations(j,i);
   }
  //perform some calculations on the temporary average table and delete it
}
```

The problem is in the combinations function. Here
    combinations(i,j)
    {
        //find all possible combinations
        //find average of all combinations
    }

I now need to store all the averages in a temporary table/data set

For ex., for i=2,j=5.. ill have ten combinations for each value of j.
so, the column count will be 10 and the row count wil be 2.

This table should be a dynamic dataset I guess.
Im not really sure what to do.. just struck.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the best solution is to initially create the i,j dataset as vertical - with each eventual-variable as a row - and then use `PROC TRANSPOSE` to transpose it to horizontal.  You can use the `ID` statement to name the variable.

Comment: sounds good.. but each time we transpose.. it creates a new table.
I just need to create once and insert rows after each iteration.

Comment: Make all of the rows at once, then transpose once.

Comment: is it possible? I mean.. lets say there are rows in table like
    d1 12
    d1 13
    d1 14
    d2 11
    d2 12
    d2 56
    d3 1
    d3 2
    d3 3

Is it possible to make a transpose table which looks like
<br/>
    12 13 14<br/>
    11 12 56<br/>
    1  2  3<br/>